# PHP - Hyperlink not getting full string

Tags: php

i have following code but unable to get full variable values on return.

```
<?php
$no7="Girls pink";
$no8="All Categories";
$aw="2";

echo'<table width="auto" border="0">
  <tr>
        <td width="auto" class="s">'; echo "<a href=search.php?search_name=".$no7."&mydropdown=".$no8."&pno=".$aw.">".$aw."</a>"; echo'</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
?>
```

Thanks for help Regards,

Comment: You aren't returning anything. Your formatting is horrible. Your HTML is invalid. Your URL is invalid. Tables are not layout tools. A 1x1 table makes no sense.

Comment: @Quentin: the HTML code seems valid to me.

Comment: @Jocelyn — `&` indicates the start of a character reference.

Comment: @Jocelyn what about href=search - needs quotes

Comment: @quention: only in 'bare' html. Within this limited example, it's just a query varaible separator.

Comment: @Fou you are not helping yourself by switching from starting strings with ' to starting with " randomly. Better to stick to the best opener   for the job at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) and [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo "<a href='search.php?search_name=" . urlencode($no7) . "&amp;mydropdown=" . urlencode($no8) . "&amp;pno=" . urlencode($aw) . "'>" . htmlspecialchars($aw) . "</a>";
```

Also: add quotes around the URL, and replace `&` with `&amp;` for better HTML syntax.

Comment: href=search.php? where are the quotes

Comment: @allen213: The quotes are there.

Answer (score 3):

Add quotes on `href` value:

```
echo "<a href='search.php?search_name=".$no7."&mydropdown=".$no8."&pno=".$aw."'>".$aw."</a>";
//            ^--------------------------- quotes ----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the horrible formatting/layout and use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc):

```
echo <<<EOL
<table width="auto" border="0">
<tr>
    <td width="auto" class="s"><a href="search.php?search_name={$no7}&mydropdown={$no8}&pno={$aw}">{$aw}</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
EOL;
```

Note how the HEREDOC removes the need for all those individual echoes, allows for variable interpolation into the string (no more 'break out of string to concatenate'), and allows for proper formatting/indentation of the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the spaces in your variables. It's more of an issue with browsers interperting spaces as the end of your href tag. As suggested earlier, use `urlencode` or convert the spaces in your variables to `+`